# How to plot the effects of various explanatory variables on the response variable

Tags: r, excel, plot, visualization

I am fitting a multivariate regression model which aims to predict the number of ice cream tubs an ice cream cart sells on a daily basis. Some of the predictors include: the number of ice cream flavors available that day, average daily temperature, and the total number of competitors in the area. In other words, we have the following model:

Number of tubs sold = Beta_0 + Beta_1 * Number of Ice Cream Flavors + Beta_2 * Average Daily Temp + Beta_3 * Number of Competitors

Assuming I have calculated the coefficients for each predictor, how can I visually display the net effect that each coefficient has on the total number of ice cream tubs sold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualizing the effects of multiple variables on the response may be difficult, but
you could experiment with [faceted scatter plots](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html).

On the other hand, a simple column graph can show the difference in magnitude between the predictor coefficients and their relative effects.

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

coefficients <- c(0.35,0.21,0.79)
predictors <- c('Flavors','Temp','Competitors')

data <- data.frame(coefficients, predictors)

ggplot(data, aes(x=predictors, y=coefficients)) + geom_col()
```

[example column chart output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RohwM.png)

Also, [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73320/how-to-visualize-a-fitted-multiple-regression-model) over on stats/stack_exchange.com has some other recommendations.

---

If you're familiar with Shiny, creating an interactive series of visuals may be the best method. I created the following small app that allows you to adjust the variable coefficients and values and see the effect on the tubs sold.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Multiple Linear Regression App"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      sliderInput(inputId = "flavors",
                  label = "Number of Ice Cream Flavors",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 30,
                  value = 1),
      
      sliderInput(inputId = "temp",
                  label = "Average Daily Temperature (F)",
                  min = -10,
                  max = 110,
                  value = 63),
      
      sliderInput(inputId = "competitors",
                  label = "Number of Competitors",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 20,
                  value = 5),
      
      sliderInput(inputId = "flavors_coef",
                  label = "Flavor Coefficient",
                  min = -20,
                  max = 20,
                  value = 6),
      
      sliderInput(inputId = "competitors_coef",
                  label = "Competitors Coefficient",
                  min = -20,
                  max = 20,
                  value = -4),
      
      sliderInput(inputId = "temp_coef",
                  label = "Temperature Coefficient",
                  min = -20,
                  max = 20,
                  value = -2)
      
    ),

    mainPanel(
      
      textOutput("sold")
      
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$sold <- renderText({
    total_sold <- ((input$flavors_coef * input$flavors) + (input$temp_coef * input$temp) + (input$competitors_coef * input$competitors))
    paste("Total Sold Tubs", total_sold)
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```